# Как закрыть полностью Android приложение при отсутствии интернет соединения?

Tags: java, android-webview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо автоматически закрыть приложение если нет интернета, чтобы избежать ошибку WebView (Страница недоступна)

Выкладываю java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private WebView webView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        SimpleWebViewClientImpl webViewClient = new SimpleWebViewClientImpl(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                        "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
            }
        });


        webView.loadUrl("https://itcreator.pro/chat/m/");



    }

    class MyJavaScriptInterface {

        private Context ctx;

        MyJavaScriptInterface(Context ctx) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        public void showHTML(String html) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).setTitle("HTML").setMessage(html)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null).setCancelable(false).create().show();

        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.webView.canGoBack()) {
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: Неправильный подход. Если я открою приложение, а оно тут же само закроется, то я его удалю и поставлю на маркете единицу. Надо не закрывать, а писать, что нет интернета.

Comment: можно сразу и телефон выключать @Эникейщик

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном ниже коде показано, как использовать ConnectivityManager для отправки запросов об активной сети и определять возможности подключения.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    return isConnected;
}
```

Закрыть приложение можно так:

```
if(!isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
   Toast.makeText(this,"No Internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   finish(); //Calling this method to close this activity when internet is not available.
}
```

Comment: Код встает без ошибок, но почему то не работает. Т.е при отсутствии конекта приложение не закрывает, почему?(